# Parse CSV to Model

Tags: c#, .net, csv, ienumerable

I'm trying to parse `CSV` to Model but, my `IEnumerable` always null. Is there something wrong with this code?

```
private IEnumerable<CandidatesDTO> FileToDto(byte[] file)
{
    System.Text.UTF8Encoding enc = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
    IEnumerable<CandidatesDTO> query = null;
    string[] separators = { ",", ".", "!", "?", ";", ":", " " };
    try
    {
        var str = enc.GetString(file);
        query = from line in str
                let data = str.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                select new CandidatesDTO
                {
                    Id = Int32.Parse(data[0]),
                    Name = data[1],
                    DOB = DateTime.Parse(data[2], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                    Phone = data[3],
                    Email = data[4]
                };
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
    return query;
}
```

**UPDATE**. I found there is Exception - "Input string was in incorrect format". Seemed like some incorrect type was passed with string and this caused FormatException.

Comment: please share your csv file content as well

Comment: Could I suggest you to add an F# project to your current solution. You could then take advantages of the CSV Type Provider as detailed here  http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/CsvProvider.html

On top of that with F#, it is fast and easy to define DTOs

Comment: The file must be empty.  You should have at least one CandidatesDTO in query and you have null.

Comment: Why not use `StreamReader` and 'ReadLine'?

Comment: Take a look at http://www.filehelpers.net

Comment: Take a look at `TextFieldParser` from Microsofts `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Have you looked at https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/#reading-reading-all-records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking at the code, I think linq is treating `str` as an `IEnumerable<char>`. You may need to do `str.Split("\r\n")` or whatever the line separator may be so you can get each lines.

```
private IEnumerable<CandidatesDTO> FileToDto(byte[] file)
{
    System.Text.UTF8Encoding enc = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
    IEnumerable<CandidatesDTO> query = null;
    string[] separators = { ",", ".", "!", "?", ";", ":", " " };
    try
    {
        var str = enc.GetString(file);
        query = from line in str.Split(new [] {"\n\r"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                let data = line.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                select new CandidatesDTO
                {
                    Id = Int32.Parse(data[0]),
                    Name = data[1],
                    DOB = DateTime.Parse(data[2], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                    Phone = data[3],
                    Email = data[4]
                };
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
    return query;
}
```

Comment: you were right - there is \n\r symbols in fews array elements and this caused FormatException.